# How I can use IBM Platform MPI with CUDA?

Tags: cuda, mpi

First of all, sorry if I make spelling mistakes, I'm not english.

I'm trying to use IBM Platform MPI v9.1.2 with CUDA 5.5 in Windows 7 to pass messages through GPUs, using CUDA-Aware MPI like this post says: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/

My GPUs (Nvidia Tesla C2075) are compatible with UVA (Unified Virtual Addressing) technology, so it should work properly when I use MPI_Ssend and MPI_Recv passing the device pointers, but it doesn't and the program crashes.

I've installed only the IBM package but I couldn't find anything about any configuration needed.

Anyone know something about this and could help me?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to switch to linux.

IBM indicates PMPI GPU-Direct support is on linux only [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&appname=gpateam&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS212-203) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/0/897/ENUS212-420/index.html&lang=en&request_locale=en)

> Hardware requirements
>   ...
>   In addition, Platform MPI supports GPU-Direct 2.0 on Linux .

CUDA-Aware MPI depends on GPUDirect, as indicated in the blog you linked.

Comment: I am the IBM Platform MPI Level 3 Support Engineer.  This answer is correct.